# Tip of a distorted and curved vector

Tags: symbols, arrows, vector, arrow-curve

Supposing to have this MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Bcirc[1][3]{\mathbin{\tikz[baseline=-#1]{\draw[thick](0,0)circle[radius=#1mm];}}}
\begin{document}
$a\Bcirc b$, $\blacktriangle, \blacktriangledown$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to properly distort black triangles to have a distorted and curved effect on the circumference like the image below?

> I.E. Is there any strategy or package to distort the black triangle symbol?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first approach with `arrows.meta` and `bending` tikz-libraries.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\R{0.750cm}
  \draw[line width=1pt](0cm,0cm) circle[radius=\R];
  \draw[line width= 1pt,arrows={-Triangle[line width=0,angle=30:15pt,bend]},shorten >=2pt](0,\R) arc(90:90-25:\R);
  \draw[line width= 1pt,arrows={-Triangle[line width=0,angle=30:15pt,bend]},shorten >=2pt](0,-\R) arc(270:270-25:\R);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]